# custom keyboard access to editText in android

Tags: java, android, keyboard

I am making a custom keyboard very similar to that described here: [Use an EditText with custom keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19262563/use-an-edittext-with-custom-keyboard)

I am adding this custom keyboard to an already existing application, and in doing so I am running into the following problem: The keyboard is initialized in the activity class. The onPress method for the keyboard is also in the activity class. However, the inputTextView which has a setText method that is supposed to be called by onPress is inside of a subclass of View that isn't accessible to the activity.
I think it has to do with the following. The main activity class contains a ListView, which contains a BaseAdapter with the following method:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
...  
equationView = new EquationView(parent.getContext());
... 
return equationView;
}
```

I can't figure out how to pass the correct ViewGroup so that the new View is returned.